# can't ping NT Server running on 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, virtual-machines, ping, windows

I have a Windows NT Server running on Virtual Machine on Windows Server 2003.

Until this morning, all worked fine - I could connect to the virtual server through my program and all was well.

This morning, for some unknown reason, outer communication with the NT server stopped working. I can connect to the NT server through the 2003 and remote control it, but I can't ping it through any other computer.

All my computers are running on a domain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean you have NT on the VM, and the VM is hosted on 2003?

And you can see NT using the virtual machine tools when using 2003's console?

Did you check the logs on the two systems?

Did you check the IP on the virtual machine?

Is there some form of software firewall running on the host or VM?

Can the VM ping out, does it have network connectivity?

Did you check the hardware configuration on the VM and on the guest OS to make sure the networking is properly bridged?

Can you ping from the host to the guest machine?

Comment: I can see the NT using the virtual machine tools.
I checked the IP on both machines - they are fine.
I can ping from the host to the guest, from the guest to the host - but not from the guest to the network, not even the Domain controller.
There is no firewall running on either machines.

Comment: And both IPs are internal (i.e., bridged)?

Comment: You haven't told us what virualization platform you're using but have you checked the virtual network settings; host only, NAT, pass-through, etc.

Comment: How do I tell if it's bridged or not? I tried looking in the Virtual Machine configuration but there's no indication of that.

Comment: Well...what platform are you using to virtualize it? One indication is usually that the IP on the VM and the host are in the same subnet, but not always.

Comment: it's a Microsoft Virtual Machine platfrom.

Comment: I tried doing route -f and the re-adding the route with comparsion to a different server of the same kind that works in some other place - but that didn't work.

Comment: I found out the when I delete this route: 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 218.1.72.254 218.1.72.40 (destination, netmask, gateway and interface) and this one: 218.1.72.0 255.255.255.0 218.1.72.40 218.1.72.40, I can't ping anything, it fails immidieatly. when I add the first rule and try pinging, it seems like it tries to find a route(takes time to fail the ping) but I still can't ping. when I add the second as well, I can ping the host machine.